# didInsertElement from controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember application with a controller `header.js` and a template `header.hbs`.

Now I have some javascript I need to execute at document `$( document ).ready()`

I saw on Ember Views there is  `didInsertElement` but how do I do this from the controller?

```
// controllers/header.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});

// views/header.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});

// templates/header.js
test
```

I read several times it's not good practice to be using Ember Views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the controller is not inserted (the view is) hence there is no didInsertElement.

If you need something to run once, you can write something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    someName: function () {  // <--- this is just some random name
        // do your stuff here
    }.on('init')  // <---- this is the important part
});
```

Comment: ah great! thank you that could do it. From all my early reading on ember I feel there is a stigma in using views or is that ill-founded?

Comment: Well, they're there for a reason. Controllers and views do very different things. For some things you can get away with just a template (but in that case, ember generates a default view on the fly anyway).

Comment: I want to invoke `Ember.$('.ui.modal').modal('show');` inside the controller which handles a route  dedicated to a modal. How can I do this?

Comment: I think this would warrant a Question/Answer on Stackoverflow. In the comments you won't get good anwers for a new question.

Comment: `Don't use Ember's function prototype extensions`, so I had to use `init: function () {...},`

Comment: This answer is over three years old, the solution might have changed since then. If it did, you'd probably help more people by writing this up as a full-fledged answer!

Answer (score 1):

A more actual answer (Ember 2.18+) while honouring the same principle as mentioned in user amenthes' answer: it's no longer advised to use Ember's function prototype extensions. Instead you can override the `init()` method of a controller directly. Do note that you'll have to call `this._super(...arguments)` to ensure all Ember-related code runs:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments); // Don't forget this!

    // Write your code here.
  }
});
```

Comment: Either I have misunderstood (quite possible ;-) or this is not correct. I have a template which makes use of a component inside a loop. Each pass through the loop creates one instance of the component. Each creation of the component invokes an action on the Controller. I would presume this looping must be happening before `$( document ).ready()` because the DOM is being adjusted but I find that the processing in the 'init' handler of the controller is finished before the calls to the action start . If I'm wrong I would be interested to know where I have misunderstood. I'm using Ember 3.x.